# How could I use AJAX requests to generate a constantly updating marker on google maps?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, flask

I would like to code an app that creates a constantly updating google map, and was told that AJAX requests would achieve this. However, upon reading the documentation, I am confused as to how I should solve my problem using this technique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to achive is a technique called polling. If you want constantly fetch some remote resource I think it's better to use [Socket.IO](https://socket.io/) (like chat system, you want a publish-subscribe architecture).

Comment: could you possibly outline how socket.io would be used in this instance?

Comment: ".. since the data updates every 10 seconds, I need a method of continually calling the data and passing it into the marker, so that in effect, it moves in real time." With Socket.IO you can make a real-time app, just like you want. I suppose you want make AJAX call (every 10 seconds) to a remote server, and update you markers, then with Socket.IO you don't need make AJAX call every 10 seconds (even 1 call every minute is very exepensive), but you have a sort of direct channel you can fetch in real time.

Comment: Would you be able to suggest a methodology of using this socket.io to fetch data from an API (just using the url as "www.api.com"?)

Comment: Socket.IO has both client and server side (Nodejs). From the tags in this question I supppose you're using Python/Flash on the server side, but if you want use Socket.IO you have to rewrite this part in javascript-NodeJS. Is this API from you want to fetch data (every 10 seconds) is made by you, or is a third part? Because if it's a third part code, in order to avoid polling, you can't use the easy pub-sub Socket.IO.

Comment: This API is third party, and I heard there is a socket.IO module for flask, as shown here: https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: I used to work with Socket.IO once, I made both client and server side (because it was a chat), so I don't know if you can use Socket.IO just on client. 

This module probably could help you to create a Socket.IO-server with Python/Flask, but if this API is a third-part that flask-socketio is not help you (because you don't need to rewrite the server-side, but just the client. As a third-part code you cannot rewrite this API).
You should see if you can make just a client with Socket.IO, using a third-part API

Comment: Ok, you can use a just Socket.IO client, with a third-part API, because I forget there's a commont example with the Twitter API (server side) http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1947699

Comment: I think you should just use three function: 
  1) socket = io(); // to connect
  2) socket.emit(); // to send or subscribe at the channel (see your API)
 3) socket.on('receive', function(data){ }); // in order to receive data

More details: https://socket.io/docs/client-api/

Comment: Hey, forget about Socket.IO, if you just implement client-side you can use https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_serversentevents.asp